# Issue with stock update on amazon with mws

Tags: amazon-mws

We are using the following details for updating the quantity of a product in amazon. Wile using scratch pad, option Feeds->SubmitFeed

Set the required parameters and pass the following XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
<Header>
<DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
<MerchantIdentifier>$merchantID</MerchantIdentifier>
</Header>
<MessageType>Inventory</MessageType>
<Message>
<MessageID>1</MessageID>
<OperationType>Update</OperationType>
<Inventory>
<SKU>$SKU</SKU>
<Quantity>8</Quantity>
</Inventory>
</Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

feed type : _POST_INVENTORY_AVAILABILITY_DATA_
we are getting in response for the same - submissionid. I know it takes sometime to update. But i waited and waited .. 4 atleast 15 hrs (not minutes) but it still was in process and the quantity was never updated.

Am getting in the following response

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SubmitFeedResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonaws.com/doc/2009-01-01/">
<SubmitFeedResult>
  <FeedSubmissionInfo>
    <FeedSubmissionId>6791310806</FeedSubmissionId>
    <FeedType>_POST_INVENTORY_AVAILABILITY_DATA_</FeedType>
    <SubmittedDate>2013-03-21T19:48:37+00:00</SubmittedDate>
    <FeedProcessingStatus>_SUBMITTED_</FeedProcessingStatus>
  </FeedSubmissionInfo>
</SubmitFeedResult>
<ResponseMetadata>
  <RequestId>fd07bf18-4f6a-4786-bdf9-9d4db50956d0</RequestId>
</ResponseMetadata>
</SubmitFeedResponse>
```

and getting in following response on checking the status of the feed

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonaws.com/doc/2009-01-01/">
<Error>
  <Type>Sender</Type>
  <Code>FeedProcessingResultNotReady</Code>
  <Message>Feed Submission Result is not ready for Feed Submission Id: 6791310806</Message>
  <Detail/>
</Error>
<RequestID>2c86128d-b53a-4fc3-80d1-6b41b53a8977</RequestID>
</ErrorResponse>
```

Can any1 guide me.. where did i go wrong .. in here? or if there is any better way to look on for the same.

Answer (score 1):

The time it seems to be taking *isn't normal*. Submitted feeds usually switch to `_IN_PROGRESS_` within a few minutes and then take another few minutes to complete, when the status switches to `_DONE_`. Short feeds like your example feed should take less than a minute to process.

In the past, I've seen one feed upload blocking another though. It seems that sometimes the MWS won't start processing one feed until a previous feed of the same user has gone trough (or for that matter: failed). Please check if you have other request that might block yours (GetFeedSubmissionList)

Apart from this, the answers you are getting from Amazon MWS are *perfectly normal*. Your feed was accepted and put into the processing queue. The queue status was set to `_SUBMITTED_`, and as long as it hasn't switched to *DONE*, you will get the `FeedProcessingResultNotReady` answer you were seeing.